# Can I repair a broken overhead door opener drive gear?

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener

The garage door motor has snapped on the gear. When the garage is activated, the motor spins but the gear doesn't turn and so neither does the chain attached to the garage.

[image: Gear]

Can I keep the garage door opener and attach a new gear by taking apart the opener?

Comment: Opener repair parts are often available. Search your model number. If not, you should be able to reuse the sprocket and build a replacement assembly using hardware store parts. Did you have a more specific question?

Comment: Have you tried removing the bolt holding the gear? If you're in luck, the bolt sheared, and you'll just need to extract it with a screw extractor and replace it with a Grade 5 bolt of the same size.

Answer (score 3):

The pictured sprocket looks fine to me. You must mean either the internal plastic sprocket or worm gear. They are available for replacement from major brands.